# What is the name of the real samurai village tourist attraction in Kyoto?

Tags: film-location, uzumasa-limelight

In the film [Uzumasa Limelight](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3290882/reference), the protagonist takes a job at a samurai village tourist attraction, presumably in Kyoto where the story is based. I'm pretty sure this place exists in the real world.

Does anyone know the name of the real samurai village tourist attraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure this place exists in the real world. Does anyone know the name of the real samurai village tourist attraction?

[Toei Kyoto Studio Park](http://www.toei-eigamura.com/en/) (東映太秦映画村, Tōei**uzumasa**eigamura) is where this movie was shot. It's literally the only theme park in Japan that also doubles as a film set for [jidaigeki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jidaigeki) films.

From an article containing an interview with Seizo Fukumoto:

> In “Uzumasa Limelight” he plays an elderly kirare-yaku named Kamiyama, facing the end of his career as the title **Uzumasa Studio in Kyoto — a real production studio that has been making period dramas for decades** — abandons its declining signature genre. A ray of hope appears in the form of Satsuki (real-life martial arts champion Chihiro Yamamoto), a young actress who is handy with a sword. She becomes Kamiyama’s apprentice, seeking to polish her technique but not knowing if she will ever use it again on the screen.

Comment: Just to clarify, when Kamiyama's "long-running samurai series is canceled, his skills are downgraded to theme park attractions for swarming tourists" (https://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/05/movies/uzumasa-limelight-about-a-fading-actor.html) is presumably different from the main filming location, where the samurai series was filmed. Is that not right? He gets a job at the same location, just a vastly different caliber of work? They are both the Toei Kyoto Studio Park?

Certainly, the Studio Park does look like it could be correct: http://www.toei-eigamura.com/en/parkmap.html

Comment: *"He gets a job at the same location, just a vastly different caliber of work? They are both the Toei Kyoto Studio Park? "* -- Correct.. the theme park has multiple on-site locations to shoot various scenes, and, after Kamiyama's TV series gets cancelled, he goes to doing little skits for the walking park guests, but he does still work at Kyoto Studio Park (until his last day, that is).